# Decode firebase short deeplink to its original data/params

Tags: node.js, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm working on a project for creating firebase short deep links. I use POST: `https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1` to generate the deep links and pass in the body info like `domainUriPrefix`, `link`, etc.

I use node and the generated link looks something like this: `https://mydoamin.page/IEhnk`.

Is there a way to decode the deep link back to get the data I passed when I first created it? Or is it possible to use that short deeplink to get its content data from the database?

Thanks.

Related Link: [Create Dynamic Links with the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest)

Answer (score 0):

firebase has some functions that you can give encoded link and then get decoded link again recommend that you see firebase documentation looking by used framework

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).